# Facebook Object Debugger Error 502 and Error parsing input URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-web-services

Well, this website uses AWS EC2, and right now when i shared the site on Facebook, facebook don't show nothing, but yesterday it work well.

Right now the Facebook lint(object debugger) says

> Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

And

> Curl Error : RECV_ERROR Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after
>   CONNECT

[image: facebook error]

But when i use curl via terminal on my Mac (like `curl -v -X TRACE www.cuinzy.com`) this return:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: www.cuinzy.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.207.48.99...
* Connected to www.cuinzy.com (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> TRACE / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: www.cuinzy.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2015 10:14:36 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: message/http
<
TRACE / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Host: www.cuinzy.com
Accept: */*

* Closing connection 0
```

Curl return response code 200 on www.cuinzy.com, and if try with url https://www.cuinzy.com/itm/572-aumento-natural-del-busto-pueraria-mirifica-100-x-500mg.html, this return:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.207.48.99...
* Connected to www.cuinzy.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.cuinzy.com
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
* Server certificate: AddTrust External CA Root
> TRACE /itm/572-aumento-natural-del-busto-pueraria-mirifica-100-x-500mg.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: www.cuinzy.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2015 10:16:25 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: message/http
<
TRACE /itm/572-aumento-natural-del-busto-pueraria-mirifica-100-x-500mg.html HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
Host: www.cuinzy.com
Accept: */*

* Closing connection 0
```

And look how the use of SSL does not represent a change, additionally, notice that at all times the http response code is 200.

And, if i click on **[See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cuinzy.com%2Fitm%2F572-aumento-natural-del-busto-pueraria-mirifica-100-x-500mg.html)** link of Facebook Lint, this only return:

```
Document returned no data
```

Ah, additionally, i try this tools(and all return http response code 200 and work fine):

- curl via terminal on mac
- http://httpstatus.io/
- http://iframely.com/debug?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cuinzy.com%2Fitm%2F572-aumento-natural-del-busto-pueraria-mirifica-100-x-500mg.html
- http://opengraphcheck.com/result.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cuinzy.com%2Fitm%2F572-aumento-natural-del-busto-pueraria-mirifica-100-x-500mg.html#.VdG3hVN_Oko
- https://coveloping.com/tools/open-graph-tag-tester

Please, if you know whats happend tell me, i dont understand...

P.S: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Go check your server’s access and error log, and see if the request by the FB scraper a) reaches your server at all, and b) how it gets answered.

Comment: I don't know whats happend... Today work fine and I dont have problems... I only remove all httpd logs and restart httpd service, but... This should not have made any change... Yesterday was also restarted the server. I don't understand..

Comment: Right now work, but sometimes this don't work.. I think it's a mistake to facebook and is affecting me.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen did you ever find a solution for this issue? I'm having the same issue with a site hosted in Azure.